# Response cookie not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

When I log I create the following cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Ortund");
// insert cookie values
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

When I request data from this cookie, I use Request.Cookies:

```
string username = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["Ortund"]["Username"]);
```

When i log out, I do this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Ortund");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

For some reason, now I'm sitting with a cookie that has an expiry date of `0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM` in *Request.Cookies["Ortund"]* and the expiry date of the cookie doesn't change no matter how many times I log in.

Have I done something wrong here? Is this even close to how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

In your logout you are creating a new instance of the cookie. Also you are using `Response.Cookies.Add` which may allow multiple cookies of the same name to be appended to the `Response`.

I would suggest you to check the `Request` for the cookie key and if it doesn't exist add the cookie.

For updating the cookie, first get the existing cookie object and use `Response.SetCookie` to update the value.

**Code**

***set***

```
if(!Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Ortund"))
{
     HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Ortund");
     // insert cookie values
     cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
     Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

***update***

```
if (Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("Ortund"))
{
     HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Ortund"];
     cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
     Response.SetCookie(cookie);
}
```